# What's the purpose of the data.info file in TWRP backup?

Tags: backup, twrp

I've backed up the **/data/** partition of my smartphone using TWRP recovery. It created 4 files on a SD card: **data.ext4.win** , **data.ext4.win.md5** , **recovery.log** and **data.info** . I know what's inside of the first three files, but I don't really know what's inside of the **data.info** file. It looks like the file is a binary one, at least I can't simply view it in any file editor. Does anyone know what's the purpose of that file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you thought, **data.info** (and any file created by TWRP and with said extension) is a binary file. Given it, I've inspected it with the Linux tool **hd**, which lets me see an hexadecimal dump along with the decoded output.

---

### Dump of the file

```
00000000  0c 00 62 61 63 6b 75 70  5f 73 69 7a 65 00 0b 00  |..backup_size...|
00000010  31 33 31 34 36 37 34 36  38 38 00 0c 00 62 61 63  |1314674688...bac|
00000020  6b 75 70 5f 74 79 70 65  00 02 00 30 00 0b 00 66  |kup_type...0...f|
00000030  69 6c 65 5f 63 6f 75 6e  74 00 05 00 37 31 30 37  |ile_count...7107|
00000040  00                                                |.|
00000041
```

---

As you may have guessed by looking at the rightmost column, those kind of files contain information such as backup size and type, as well as the file count.

*Before you ask, do not delete those files. Should you do so, TWRP won't probably be able to restore your backup. Delete them only if you're brave and have a backup.*

Comment: I'm not going to delete them. I was just curious what's in there. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @MikhailMorfikov You know, those answers are meant to be for future use, so I saw wise to mention that side note. Happy that my inspection was useful.